# Not able to add search control using leaflet search plugin and angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to add leaflet-search control and  below is the code:

```
angular.extend(_scope, { london: { lat: 28.7041,
                lng: 77.1025,
                zoom: 12
            },
            controls1: {

                    search: {
                                url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
                                jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
                                propertyName: 'display_name',
                                propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
                                marker: L.circleMarker([0,0],{radius:30}),
                                autoCollapse: false,
                                autoType: false,
                                minLength: 2,
                                collapsed: false    
                    }

            },
            layers1: {
                baselayers: {
                    mapbox_light: {
                        name: 'Mapbox Light',
                        url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapid}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={apikey}',
                        type: 'xyz',
                        layerOptions: {
                            apikey: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibmFyZXNoczMzIiwiYSI6ImNqZXNnanB3eDI2OG8yeG11Y2V0cWhjcmUifQ.vo8zz1cmjq47LCpWIan-_A',
                            mapid: 'mapbox.streets',
                            noWrap: true
                        },
                        worldCopyJump: true,
                        layerParams: {
                            showOnSelector: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                overlays: {
                    search: {
                        name: 'search',
                        type: 'group',
                        visible: true,
                        layerParams: {
                            showOnSelector: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I am getting this error : TypeError: L.Control.Search is not a constructor.

Have added leaflet-search.js in index html

```
<script src="leaflet-search-master/dist/leaflet-search.min.js"></script>
```

I am able to do this in separate work-space using Angular6 and without using angular-leaflet directive, however when I try this using angular leaflet directive it's giving above error

Am I missing something to add search control ?
Have I added dependencies correctly ?

Comment: I have also tried without Angular-leaflet directive, However getting same error.

Comment: var map = new L.Map('demoMap', {zoom: 9, center: new L.latLng([position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude]) });
        map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

Comment: var searchBox= new L.Control.Search({
            url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
            jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
            propertyName: 'display_name',
            propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
            marker: L.circleMarker([0,0],{radius:30}),
            autoCollapse: false,
            autoType: false,
            minLength: 2,
            collapsed: false, 
            });

Comment: map.addControl(searchBox);

Comment: I think i found the answer, I just added one import statement and it worked for me

import 'leaflet-search';

It was because dependency was not added correctly